# Accessing %(PreprocessorDefinitions) from Pre-Build Event command line in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, preprocessor

I’m having some difficulty with the Visual Studio 2010 build process.  To put it simply, I would like to pass the preprocessor definitions set up for the currently building configuration into a batch file via the Pre-Build Event command line.

The preprocessor definitions are in the projects properties under C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions.  I do see the name of the macro as %(PreprocessorDefinitions) when in that property sheet, however that macro doesn’t show up in the Macro list for Build Events > Pre-Build Event.

Is there any way to access %(PreprocessorDefinitions) from within the Build Events > Pre-Build Event > Command Line?

Thanks!

**Additional Details:**

Let me be more specific…  I’m using a slightly modified version of vs-android in order to build Android apps from within Visual Studio.  I have in the past edited the vs-android source to add specific elements we need to the build process.  I’ve noticed that the PreprocessorDefinitions are in an ItemDefinitionGroup called “ClCompile”.  I can’t seem to access the defines using %(ClCompile.PreprocessorDefinitions) from within the .props or .xml build files.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to make %(ClCompile.PreprocessorDefinitions) part of the environment, so perhaps it will show up as $( PreprocessorDefinitions)?  If so, I have not been able to find out how.

Comment: Yes, difficult.  It is a property of the ClCompile target and can be different for every .cpp file in the project.  Pre-Build is too early and the property value is ambiguous.  Hard to come up with an alternative that doesn't involve major surgery.  Duplication is the sloppy but simple solution.

Comment: Thanks much @Hans, it does seem challenging.  Perhaps the only “clean” way would be to have a set of solution wide defines for a particular configuration and merge them with the ClCompile specific defines at build time.  Then I could pass in the configuration specific defines which would let my script know what to do for each configuration.  I don’t know of a built-in way to do this in Visual Studio 2010 though, so I probably have to tweak vs-android to somehow include an extra string list that is for each configuration.